# Change in code while debugging in java class with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, performance

While debugging a java class. If I change only a single line, then is there a need to do a clean install and rerun the server. How to make it possible to do a change in the class and save the class and then able to debug with the new code without doing a clean install and again server up.

Comment: It's not possible. Java needs to recompile and execute. You may install Eclipse plugins to accelerate this process, like `JRebel` (check if your Eclipse is compatible)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood the problem fully. But as far as I know, you need to recompile so that op codes of .class files are changed corresponding to every change in code so that it is reflected at the server end where the project is deployed.